# bash while loop gives syntax error saying missing '['

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash scripting and am having trouble trying to get this to work

```
local attempt=1
local success=false
while [[ "$attempt" -le "$retryAttempt" && "$success" -eq "false"]]; do
    if ! [[ some condition here]]; 
    then
        echo true
        return            
    fi
done
```

I'm getting an error on the while condition saying
`line 10: [: missing` ]

I cannot figure out what is wrong here, suggestions anyone?

Comment: Space is needed  between the string inside the `[[ ` and the closing `]]`

Comment: https://shellcheck.net is always your friend

Comment: In shell syntax, spaces are important delimiters; do not add or remove them unless you specifically  know that it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

**Short:** insert spaces around braces

**Long**: I wouldn't consider myself a bash pro (no idea what local is), but in a minimal syntax example (which is actually an infinity loop).

```
while [ $b -le $a] ; do 
  b=$a
done
```

gives me the same error. Changing the first line to

```
while [ $b -le $a ] ; do
```

works.

Depending on the complexity of the script, you might want to consider python or perl. In my opinion bash syntax can be a real pain in the a**. Especially when passing arguments with spaces through more than one level.

Comment: Basically you are right, but your example is misleading: While the `]` is simply supposed to be an argument to the command `[` (`[` checks that its last argument is a lone `]`). From the viewpoint of grammar, `[` is not different than, say, `ls` or `echo`., `[[` .. `]]` however is a _syntactic_ shell construct, and hence bash designers could have decided that a space is not necessary. For instance, they made the space optional before a `))`, which is also just shell syntax. Alas, they decided that `]]`, although delimiting the context introduced by `[[`, must be prepended by a space.